# Making object of items in decending order data object in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In vue.js, in my data object I have an object of items that are sorted in one order. I want to make it in decending order.
My vue template looks like below snippet -

```
<div class="form-element form-element-checkbox" :key="key" v-for="(value, key) in items">
          <input
            :id="getID(value)"
            type="checkbox"
            :value="value"
            @change="updateFilter"
            v-model="selections"
            :checked="isSelected(value)">
          <label class="chk-small" :for="getID(value)">
            <span :aria-label="`Rated ${key}.0 out of 5`" class="star-rating noBlank" :style="{ width: `${key * 20}px` }"></span>
          </label>
        </div>
```

And items object looks like

```
data() {
      return {
        items: {
          5: 'item_5',
          4: 'item_4',
          3: 'item_3'
        },
        selections: []
      };
    },
```

Storing data in that order does't work.Tried to use items.slice().reverse() also. What might be wrong here ? I'm not able to get.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Firstly, instead of the items being stored with a numeric key, you should be storing them as an array.

Comment: Second, you can use `reduce` to sort on-the-fly, or whenever you want with a method

Comment: I have tried items.slice().reverse() and computed : { reverseItem() { return this.items.slice().reverse() }}

Comment: @TristanSeifert it is throwing error as "Typeerror: slice is not a function"

Comment: @pratikshaparsewar I think Derek's comment is the key.  slice() is an array method, items isn't an array.

Comment: yeah, the sooner you convert the data into an array, the sooner you can use array functions, like `filter` to sort your display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot / do not want to change your `items` dictionary into an array, you can simply use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to extract its keys and work on them.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      items: {
        // Note: even though you write them in descending order,
        // the JS engine will list them in ascending order.
        5: 'item_5',
        4: 'item_4',
        3: 'item_3',
      },
    };
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>itemsKeys: {{Object.keys(items)}}</p>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="(key, keyIndex) of Object.keys(items).reverse()">
      keyIndex: {{keyIndex}} / item key: {{key}} / item value: {{items[key]}}
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```